# Change cursor in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, dom

guys. I am struggling with changing my cursor on my Angular(7) APP. I need to set a custom cursor on the whole app when a variable is set or unset it when the variable is initialized. Have you ever experienced this kind of issue before? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set global css attributes in styles.css or styles.scss which css type u used.

you can set in css with class like

```css
 .your_class_name {
    cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/meh.png"), auto;
  }
```

```html
  <label  class="your_class_name">Smile</label>
```